# What is the best way to farm Gemstones (Amber, Topaz, Ruby, Sapphire and Diamond)?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Is there a way to farm gemstones at a quick pace in *The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild*? I'm not sure if I should go with mining, hunting Taluses, or killing as many silver enemies as I can. Please tell me which way I should go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I've observed, Silver Bokoblins are guaranteed to drop 2 gems, a combination of rubies, sapphires and diamonds. But your best bet is to find rare ore nodes, map them, then make the rounds when you want a lot of gems. Silver Lizalfos and Silver Moblins also drop a couple of gems too.

Comment: when do the ore nodes regenerate? blood moons?

Comment: No, they regenerate at the same rate as other resources from what I've seen.

Comment: "same rate" meaning there is a specific amount of time that passes and then they regen in that moment?

Comment: For what it's worth, I was only very rarely seeing silver bokoblins before I had 3 divine beasts

Comment: Are rare ore nodes a special type of node? Or can any black glittery node have gems?

Comment: @Kat They're fixed.

Comment: @Kat There are 3 types of ore node - "Luminous", "Rare", and normal. AFAIK you can get gems from any of them, but the chance is lower for luminous and normal, while the rare nodes always drop at least one gem. You can take a picture of each node type with your camera rune and then track them with the Sheikah Sensor+.

Answer (score 7):

1. I've been scanning amiibos like crazy. Not so great for the non-Zelda amiibos, but definitely helpful *with* the Zelda amiibos.
2. Mark spots on the map where there are gemstone clusters and then I hit them up as soon as a blood moon passes.
3. Don't forget ALL kinds of containers. I may have herped a derp on this one but I only realized a week or 2 ago that the steel containers drop gems, rupees, and ancient tech.
4. Fighting Taluses. They're hard, but they drop a ton of gems.

Comment: I doubt the OP is out to sell the gemstones for rupees. The only reason to do that is to try stemming the 50K initial price for the house, which isn't an attempt the game acknowledges (you get the "discount proposal" even if you have the 50K with you) so there's no point. Much more likely, they aim to upgrade gear. Also, I've never seen gems (or ancient tech, for that matter) drop from crates or similar, only rupees, food and arrows.

Answer (score 2):

The places I can recommend are the Faron Regions, Gerudo Highlands and/or Goron City/Death Mountain. I have found 1 or 2 at Akkala as well. I'm currently trying to get some sapphires. If I find good places while sapphire hunting, I'll be sure to tell you. I'm also pretty sure that gemstones don't come back on blood moons. I have found they re-spawn the same as other resources. I've found it is best to mine around Akkala or just find Stone Taluses.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the top of death mountain. You will find a significant amount of jewels, from flint to diamonds. The jewels you are most likely to get are:

- Rubies
- Sapphires
- Amber
- Opal
- Topaz
- and Flint

Answer (score 1):

With two-handed swords/hammers/etc. (i.e. the two-handed stuff that aren't spears), Taluses feel like a Gemstone *farm.* More often than not, one single Massive Swing will take them down within seconds. You'll specifically want to seek out Taluses that have their geode on top, rather than towards the rear (although that other kind can also be taken out rather easily - move around it, shoot a Bomb Arrow, get in position while it's getting up again, rinse and repeat).

Silver enemies drop much less than Taluses, but if that's good enough for you, here's another option: Later in game, there is a type of enemy you encounter semi-frequently. Those drop gemstones as well. The enemy I speak of are

> Yiga officers

which start spawning after you

> kill Kohga in the Yiga Hideout during your Vah Naboris quest.

Given that you're already familiar with Silver enemies, you shouldn't be far from the point where you meet them. Also don't worry:

> Unlike during the Yiga Hideout mission, they don't one-shot you when encountered out there.

Geodes found around are common, but to me it feels like they take ages to respawn, much longer than Taluses anyway. The same goes for rocks, plus you can also find stuff below them you're not interested in (bugs, lizards and you also don't need rupees I'll assume). Don't focus on these or non-Talus enemies too much, but they're a nice little extra to your total, so don't neglect them entirely either.

Another option I keep forgetting: If you're really in need of Gemstones, you can buy them in

> Tarrey Town

after a tiny bit of progress into the sidequest

> From the Ground Up; you need to acquire the Goron. You can find him in the Southern Mine.